# Is there any way in elasticsearch to get a part of searching result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know if there is some way to get a part of result in elasticsearch?
For exmaple, there are 100 searching results and want to get 20 results from 50 to 70.

Comment: JAVA code: SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setQuery( 
                qb).setFrom(from).setSize(size);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `from` and `size` fields on [URI](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html) or in the search [request](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html).